# argparse read in txt file

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to read a text file. In the second step I loop through the files and then I am trying to show the results in the command line.

I have a couple of problems:

1. I am not sure whether I managed to read in the text file, there is no error message, but
   the outcome does not come
2. I get an error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'P' referenced before assignment - although
   I defined the variables before the function
3. The function works  and prints the desired value but not when running it in the command line
   with argparse

The code runs as "python filename.py textfile" in the command line

Checking other threads on agrparse did not help.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename')
args = parser.parse_args()

A = 0  # the number of characters are 0 in the beginning
B = 0
C = 0
D = 0

with open(args.filename) as file:

    def rooms():



        with open("rooms.txt", "r") as in_file:
            lines = in_file.readlines()

        for line in lines:
            if "A" in line:
                W+=line.count("A") #I use the count method to count each character in a specific row
            if "B" in line:
                B+=line.count("B")
            if "C" in line:
                C+=line.count("C")
            if "D" in line:
                D+=line.count("D")

    rooms()

# if __name__=='main__main':
    print(f'total:\nA: {A} B: {B} C: {C} D: {D}')
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: you're not using the argument you pass in because you hardcoded `rooms.txt` as the file in your script

Comment: Could you elaborate on the purpose and clarify what you're trying to do? Are you trying to read the text file and count the number of times the letters appear in the file?

Comment: QueenSvetlana- Yes exactly, I am trying to read in the text file. In the second step I loop through the files and then I am trying to show the results in the command line

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues with the code if it is full code:

1)indentation : Not clear indentation in your code, so it is not executed as intended.

2)syntax: There should be at least 2 blank lines after completing your function code, so that code goes into function.

3)Separate out your function definition & function call. Create your function definition (def rooms()) outside file open.

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with you code, some of which is mentioned by [KiranM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69337933/17009055).

Other issues are:

- You have two different sources for accepting files, `argsparse` and a hard coded filename.
- You can accomplish want you want with a `dictionary` and `if` statement.
- You read in the lines twice, with the for loop and `in_file.readlines()`.

```
def room(filename::str): # or a Path object.
    letters = {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0, "D":0}
    with open(filename, "r") as in_file:
        for line in in_file:
            if line in letters:
                letters[line] = letters[line] + 1
    return letters

# In main:
print(room("room.txt"))
```